# Websocket ratchet codeigniter failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, ratchet

I have spent 2 days searching and attempting to debug and have seen lots of StackOverflow questions with the same problem but no good answers.  It's either `ssl`, which I created for `Xampp`, or something other than that which I assure you I saw and tried.

I'm working on a project where I need to implement real time notification using `codeigniter` and I can't figure out why I get this error:

> WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:3030/demo/server.php' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

I already tried different methods and `wss` using `430 80 8080`.. every port and every method.

Comment: have you try [pusher](https://pusher.com/docs), it simple and powerful for realtime notification

Comment: @Ascaliko no i'm letting it as the last solution, i want to use ratchet so i get to know how everything works, or pusher is good enough and it's useless for me to learn how websockets work ? Ty.

Comment: Just Remove 'ws://localhost:3030/demo/server.php' To- ws://Your_IP_Here:8080/demo/server.php